# Pivotal Cloud Foudry Elastic Runtime Install hangs at "Installing Elastic Runtime"

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am installing Pivotal Cloud Foundry on VCD. Ops Manager installation went through fine but Elastic Runtime install hangs after 52% at "Installing Pivotal Elastic Runtime". I don't see any error on verbose output. Here is last few lines where it is stuck.

```
Started creating bound missing vms > doppler-partition-null-az/0 
Done creating bound missing vms > diego_cell-partition-null-az/1 (00:02:55) 
Started creating bound missing vms > loggregator_trafficcontroller-partition-null-az/0 
Done creating bound missing vms > diego_cell-partition-null-az/2 (00:02:57) 
Done creating bound missing vms > doppler-partition-null-az/0 (00:03:28)
```

I keep seeing following when debug the corresponding task

```
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:05 #1681] [] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Renewing lock: lock:deployment:cf-6c242417fd8fb52ed3fd
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:10 #1681] [] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Renewing lock: lock:deployment:cf-6c242417fd8fb52ed3fd
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:15 #1681] [] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Renewing lock: lock:deployment:cf-6c242417fd8fb52ed3fd
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:20 #1681] [] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Renewing lock: lock:deployment:cf-6c242417fd8fb52ed3fd
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:25 #1681] [] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Renewing lock: lock:deployment:cf-6c242417fd8fb52ed3fd
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:30 #1681] [] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Renewing lock: lock:deployment:cf-6c242417fd8fb52ed3fd
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:30 #1681] [task:13-checkpoint] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: (0.000283s) SELECT NULL
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:30 #1681] [task:13-checkpoint] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: (0.000100s) BEGIN
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:30 #1681] [task:13-checkpoint] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: (0.000289s) UPDATE "tasks" SET "checkpoint_time" = '2016-04-05 03:44:30.678779+0000' WHERE ("id" = 13)
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:30 #1681] [task:13-checkpoint] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: (0.001109s) COMMIT
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:35 #1681] [] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Renewing lock: lock:deployment:cf-6c242417fd8fb52ed3fd
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:40 #1681] [] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Renewing lock: lock:deployment:cf-6c242417fd8fb52ed3fd
D, [2016-04-05 03:44:45 #1681] [] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: Renewing lock: lock:deployment:cf-6c242417fd8fb52ed3fd
```

[link]https://gist.github.com/iotware/6a733cd3426217390702aee51f4993fd

Comment: Can you put the full logs in a gist or pastebin and update your question with a link to those logs?

Comment: It's 36 M file, I thinking how to pass it you.

Comment: Error 1, [2016-04-04 09:29:41 #1681] [create_vm(85d376fc-0547-4092-ade4-4df8aaa14c66, urn:vcloud:catalogitem:5c7dc77c-db1f-4ac8-bacc-821e193a7c55, {"ram"=>1024, "disk"=>20480, "cpu"=>2}, ...)] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: REST RES 400 {:date=>"Mon, 04 Apr 2016 09:29:41 GMT", :content_type=>"application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.error+xml;version=5.5", :content_length=>"372"} <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: <Error xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5" minorErrorCode="DUPLICATE_NAME" message="The VCD entity pcf_catalog already exists." majorErrorCode="400" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5 http://vcore5-us01.oc.vmware.com/api/v1.5/schema/master.xsd"></Error>

Comment: [create_vm(3dcbc7c9-0f6f-4dbf-8093-24647b71a4aa, urn:vcloud:catalogitem:5c7dc77c-db1f-4ac8-bacc-821e193a7c55, {"ram"=>1024, "disk"=>2048, "cpu"=>1}, ...)]  WARN -- DirectorJobRunner: Attempting to retry POST request against https://vcore5-us01.oc.vmware.com/api/vApp/vapp-6c76e985-1b70-4d94-af58-9ad5e26fa710/action/recomposeVApp after 4 unsuccessful attempts. Latest error: 500 Internal Server Error: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
minorErrorCode="INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" message="Unable to perform this action. Contact your cloud administrator." majorErrorCode="500"

Comment: D, [2016-04-04 10:35:19 #1681] [create_vm(3dcbc7c9-0f6f-4dbf-8093-24647b71a4aa, urn:vcloud:catalogitem:5c7dc77c-db1f-4ac8-bacc-821e193a7c55, {"ram"=>1024, "disk"=>2048, "cpu"=>1}, ...)] DEBUG -- DirectorJobRunner: REST RES 500 {:date=>"Mon, 04 Apr 2016 10:35:19 GMT", :content_type=>"application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.error+xml;version=5.5", :content_length=>"401"} <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5" minorErrorCode="INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" message="Unable to perform this action. Contact your cloud administrator." majorErrorCode="500" ></Error>

Comment: Finally I was able to pull smaller log. Here is gist of log which failed. https://gist.github.com/iotware/6a733cd3426217390702aee51f4993fd